# GNU GRUB cmd before booting he system

Tags: boot, grub2, gnu

I performed a clean installation of Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, in the installation process the OS asked me to create a EFI partition, and so I did a "/" partition, EFI partition and a swap partition.

My "problem" is, everytime that I boot the system a gnu grub command line appears, and wait for a input, I type "exit" and the system boot up normaly.

How can I fix this?

[image: GNU GRUB CMD]

Comment: What brand/model system? This will show details like if UEFI or BIOS. May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: its a Asus X510UR, i'll try to use the boot repair to see what's going on

Comment: This question has got no answers? The same happens to me with UBUNTU 20.04

Comment: It's been a while since this happened, but if I would guess that, the boot-repair solution worked just fine. I had weekly issues using Ubuntu 16.04... don't know the recent ubuntu versions tho.